# UK transit visa on arrival for Italian refugee or travel documents holder

Tags: uk, transit-visas, italy, lhr, refugees

I'm gonna travel from Stockholm to Rome via British airways but have long layover in London Heathrow.

My question is:

1. Do I need transit visa to go outside airport and just explore city?
2. if I do require visa can I get that visa on arrival to UK on the airport from British border control officer?

Comment: The UK does not issue visas on arrival, transit or otherwise.  Whether you need a transit visa will likely depend on your citizenship, irrespective of holding an Italian-issued travel document. You can check which visa you need, if any, via the link in the duplicate question.

Comment: Note that in addition to the _titolo di viaggio per stranieri_ you also need to bring your _permesso di soggiorno_ (the red and blue card version, not the paper version).

Comment: Anyone answer me please

Comment: I didn't get it